# json to sqflite create table query Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there an automatic way to generate sqflite create table queries according to json data?
I m building Erp apps.So, i have to deal with 40-50 tables each time and
i think there should be an automatic way to do it like json to dart.

```
    {
        "sto_code": "120.001",
        "sto_name": "NORMAL STOK",
        "sto_amount": 1
    }
```

Comment: Would you have an example of the json data?

Comment: @rapaterno very basic json data

Comment: Do you want to create a model from the json data? if so you could use https://app.quicktype.io/, there you can drop your json and it will generate the corresponding dart model.

Comment: @RuudvandenBoomen
i want to generate the database create query for sqflite => CREATE TABLE Stocks (sto_no INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,sto_code TEXT, sto_amount int)

Comment: Then you can use the following website https://www.convertjson.com/json-to-sql.htm

Comment: @RuudvandenBoomen i have already checked the link. it s for sqlite.  In sqflite there is no VARCHAR and other some data types :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No package that I know of does that yet. But you could use this code snippet to generate a CREATE TABLE statement with an example json file.

```
  String getType(Type type){
    if(type is int){
      return 'INTEGER';
    }else if(type is String){
      return 'TEXT';
    }else if(type is double){
      return 'REAL';
    }else{
      return 'TEXT';
    }
  }
  
  
  String createColumns(Map<dynamic, dynamic> map){
    String columns = '';
    map.forEach((key, value){
      columns += '$key ${getType(value.runtimeType)}, ';
    });
    
    return columns.endsWith(', ') ? columns.substring(0,columns.length - 2) : columns;
  }
  
  String createTable(String tableName, Map<dynamic, dynamic> map){
    String columns = createColumns(map);
    String table = 'CREATE TABLE $tableName ($columns)';
    
    return table;
  }
```

Comment: it seems that, there s not an online tool to do it. i will try to build something like this. thank you for your help sir.